# How to draw a circle on image given float (subpixel) coordinates of it center

Tags: python, graphics, computer-vision, drawing

I want to visualize results of keypoint tracking algorithm in python. I have a sequence of (Image, Keypoint) pairs (video basically). Tracking algorithm is strong enough to give me subpixel accuracy. But i have no idea, how to visualize it properly.

I tried to round my coordinates and draw a circle by `cv2.circle(image, (int(round(x)), int(round(y))))`, but it leads to visual jittering of my keypoints due to small image resolution.

I checked OpenCV, Pillow, skimage, Pygame (`pygame.draw.circle`). All of them cannot properly draw circle with float coordinates.

Comment: If you are not limited to Python, `p5.js` works well with float coordinates.

Comment: You could try Python Wand, which is based upon ImageMagick.

Comment: @tanmay_garg unfortunately i limited to Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DIPlib has the function [`DrawBandlimitedBall()`](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/generation_drawing.html#dip-DrawBandlimitedBall-dip-Image-L-dip-dfloat--dip-FloatArray--Image-Pixel-CL-dip-String-CL-dip-dfloat--dip-dfloat-), which draws a disk or a circle with smooth transitions and with floating-point origin coordinates (disclosure: I'm one of the authors). You might need to draw the circle in an empty image, then blend it in to get the effect you are looking for. Code would look something like this:

```py
import diplib as dip

img = dip.ImageRead('/Users/cris/dip/images/flamingo.tif')
p = [366.4, 219.1]

# Create an empty image and draw a circle in it
circle = dip.Image(img.Sizes(), 1, 'SFLOAT')
circle.Fill(0)
dip.DrawBandlimitedBall(circle, diameter=22.3, origin=p, value=1, mode='empty')
circle /= dip.Maximum(circle)

# Blend: img * (1-circle) + circle * color
img *= 1 - circle
img += circle * dip.Create0D([0,255,0]) # we make the circle green here

img.Show()
dip.ImageWrite(img, 'so.jpg')
```

[image: flamingo image with a green circle added]

(Note that the circle actually looks better without the JPEG compression artifacts.)

You could draw the circle directly in the image, but this function adds the circle values to the image, it doesn't attempt to blend, and so you'd get a much worse look for this particular application.

Comment: Actually pretty good solution, even API quite bizarre, thank you! May i ask you? Is it possible to draw several circles in one time?

Comment: @Dark_Daiver The function draws one circle at the time. But you can draw many circles in the `circle` image and then blend once. Why do you say that the API is bizarre?